# What is the difference between LSB/g , Count/g and mV/g?

Tags: accelerometer

I know that all this are used to measure sensitivity in accelerometers. It's easy to understand the concept of mV/g but I didn't find any useful information about LSB/g and Count/g. Is there any relation between them?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question is kinda off topic for Stack overflow, you should try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ you might have more luck getting an answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accelerometer has an analog output in mV.  That's converted by an [A to D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter), resulting in a number of some range.  (E.g., a 12-bit A to D would give a number between 0 and 4095.)  LSB/g and count/g would give the sensitivity of this output number.

See [here](http://www.kionix.com/how-do-you-calculate-acceleration-digital-output-accelerometer-0) for an example.